# Javascript Mouse event isTrusted false on Chrome in Https connection

Tags: mouseevent

I am having an issue with chrome on https connection related to MouseEvent isTrusted property.

I have an HTML like

```
<div id="facebook_share">
   <a href="#">
      <img src="facebook.png" alt="facebook">
   </a>
</div>
```

Now I am opening a popup with facebook url using following javascript

```
    socialSharePopup = function (link, title) {
        window.open(link, title, 'width=400,height=380');
    };

    documentUrl = document.URL;

    documentMetaDesc = getMetadata("description");

    facebookLink = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + documentUrl;

    facebookLinkEle = document.getElementById("facebook_share");

    if (facebookLinkEle !== null) {
        facebookLinkEle.onclick = function (event) {
            //event.isTrusted is false on chrome on https
            socialSharePopup(facebookLink, 'Facebook');
            if (event) { //If Condition used for IE8
                if (event.preventDefault) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    event.returnValue = false;
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Now the issue I am facing is, on chrome when this page is opened on https connection then a popup blocker is opened first time and popup opens when clicked second time without making any changes. I find this behavior weird.

When the same site is opened on http connection then it working fine and no popup is blocked.

Same result happens when website is opened on `https` with untrusted connection (on local with no certificate)

Upon debugging I find that `MouseEvent.isTrusted (event.isTrusted)` property is false in case of popup is blocked on https

What is the relation between isTrusted and https connection ? Why its false only on https ? And why only first time ?

Its working fine on Firefox and IE

One more observation is that when user clicks happens on `div#facebook_share` it works fine (`event.isTrusted is true`) but when click happens on `<a>` tag its false.

Removing `<a>` tag is not an option as HTML is dynamically generated

How can this issue be resolved ?